# Oracle Trigger only activates the first IF statement

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a trigger that has multiple IF statements (not elseif). I did bring the code back down to having twice the same IF statement but only the first IF statement is run.

Is this standard Oracle trigger behavior? one of the if statements is pretty much hard-coded while the other uses a function so there is only a select few cases where both IFs are to be run.

Is there a different way to approach an issue like this? or would the issue be in the trigger code and should i post it here?

the code below has this behavior on our server but is dummied down from the original.

```
create or replace TRIGGER V_INV_TRANS_BIZTALK 
AFTER INSERT ON INVENTORY_TRANSACTION 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
l_type pre_advice_header.user_def_type_4%type;
l_status order_header.status%TYPE;
l_from_loc_zone location.zone_1%TYPE;
l_to_loc_zone location.zone_1%TYPE;
l_patype pre_advice_header.pre_advice_type%type;
l_retour pre_advice_header.user_def_type_6%TYPE;
l_client pre_advice_header.client_id%TYPE;

BEGIN
l_client := :new.client_id;

--Client_id = SD
IF l_client = 'SD'
THEN 

  CASE

    --InBound + Return : Pre_Advice_header
    WHEN (:new.code = 'PreAdv Status' and :new.notes in ('In Progress --> Complete')) THEN
          select PRE_ADVICE_TYPE
      into l_patype
    from pre_advice_header 
    where pre_advice_id = :new.reference_id 
    and client_id = :new.client_id;

  END CASE;
END IF;

--TRANSPARIX
IF l_client = 'SD'
--(beldba.is_transparix_client(p_client_id => :new.client_id) = '1' )
THEN 
  CASE  
    --Order is shipped
    WHEN (:new.notes like ('%--> Shipped')) THEN  
      --TRANSEXT
          INSERT INTO beldba.biztalk_trigger
          (
            event_id,
            status,
            system_id,
            client_id,
            reference_id,
            receiver_id,
            user_def_type_1
          )
          VALUES
          (
            'TRANSExt',
            'Pending',
            'DCS',
            :new.client_id,
            :new.reference_id,
            'TRANSPARIX',
            ''
          );      
  END CASE;
END IF;

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION when others then
  NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Would be worth putting some code down. I'd then probably move to say you should try and keep away from triggers unless you absolutely have to use them. Keep your code in PL/SQL to keep things transparent to developers and to prevent code executing badly. More details on when to use triggers here: www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o58asktom-101055.html

Comment: @Fudztown i added some code. the first IF had parts removed but it still causes my trigger, the second IF to not work if it follows after it. Also, in my search, i have also found out that topic on what the issues are with triggers. an interesting read, but i wouldn't know how to not use triggers on a database i can't add columns to. (the trigger table is in a different schema)

Comment: I think the second IF is probably being called. But check your case statement, maybe a second percent and check the case (capital letters etc) of the statement: CASE  
    --Order is shipped
    WHEN (:new.notes like '%--> Shipped%') THEN

Comment: @Fudztown  when i switch the IF statements around though, my IF is getting executed. the first IF doesn't really do anything that changes data as far as i can see.

Comment: What happens when you change the case statements to IF statements?

Comment: @Fudztown Then it works. but why?

Comment: I'll be honest. I've never used case statements like that. only really used them in SQL statements to get the correct data into columns. Glad it's fixed now! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two problems here:

1. If there are no matching cases in the `CASE` statement, and there is no `ELSE` clause, the `CASE` statement will raise an ORA-06592 error 'CASE not found when executing CASE statement'.  If you don't want to do anything when there is no matching case, add the following section to your `CASE` statement:

   ```
   ELSE
     NULL;
   ```
2. You end your trigger with

   ```
   EXCEPTION when others then
     NULL;
   ```

   This swallows all exceptions, including the one that Oracle was raising to tell you that it couldn't find a `CASE` to execute.  Of course, as this is at the end of your trigger, once your trigger raises an exception no further trigger code gets executed.

   `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL` is, quite frankly, a cardinal sin in Oracle.   I cannot recommend strongly enough deleting this section of your trigger.

Comment: So, the trigger crashes everytime it doesn't find a case, which is 95% of the time in the first statement. That also explains why it stops on the first statement. I'll be honest, i don't really know much about triggers and i'm building on code from predecessors. where will these oracle errors go if an insert happens? would the client software that inserts in the database get the error?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but i have been working further on this and removing the "cardinal sin" makes the trigger always error on ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger. We have always had a commit in triggers but it seems it is not allowed. could you confirm that i am correct in thinking that our triggers basically have always failed but we never noticed due to the insert happening before the commit and the EXCEPTION eating the error?

Comment: @Andy: re your first comment, the Oracle errors go nowhere.  They get swallowed.  There would be no way for any client software to know that this error had happened.  Re your second comment, I would agree with your thinking.  Note however that triggers that declare an autonomous transaction (I don't know if you have any such triggers) *can* commit that transaction.

Comment: Thanks, the first question was in case the last part was removed. This does cause the client software to display an oracle error. For that reason, i can't remove the error black hole since any error in a trigger should never crash the host system.  would you normally have a "exception when others log error"?

Comment: @Andy: Normally, I wouldn't have an 'exception when others then log error' section at all.  However, I don't know your system nor your 'client software' so I can't say whether it would be okay for an INSERT on an underlying table to go ahead with the trigger's work being only partially done or not done at all.  If you have to suppress errors from your client, write them to a log and check the log frequently.  If something is going wrong it's always better to know about it sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the case statements and replacing with IF statements resolved the issue.